# Connecting to Cloud SQL (MySQL) From IPv6 Fails

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

My ISP uses ipV6 so I'm unable to connect to my CloudSQL instance with MySqlWorkbench. I can connect via gcloud but only after installing a proxy recommended (and only used) by gcloud.

I've been told that I can:

- Install and use a proxy on my laptop, but MySqlWorkbench 8.0 has no configuration for a proxy server (despite exhaustive searches).
- Use a VPN that will convert my outgoing traffic to ipv4 somehow.
- Just use mysql command line. This does work for me but I much prefer to use the Workbench.

Has anyone run into this problem and found an efficient way to overcome it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Cloud SQL Proxy?

Comment: @enocom. I had to install gcloud beta sql connect, but I'm not sure which proxy was installed.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the cloud sql proxy https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy (which you might have installed). If that doesn't work, I'd be curious what error you see.